# How to use AutoHotKey to make R-Control function as R-Win

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, autohotkey

I have a keyboard that doesn't have a R-Win key, but software that I use requires R-Win specifically for some keyboard shortcuts. I'm trying to remap the R-Ctrl key I never use to R-Win using AutoHotKey. I have used this simple remapping so far:

RCtrl::RWin

This works fine when using R-Ctrl on its own. but when using R-Ctrl in conjunction with R-Alt to simulate R-Win + R-Alt, I get an extra R-Ctrl signal when debugging in keyboard tester programs. This causes the keyboard shortcut to not work in the software I'm using.

Anybody have an idea how to get a completely functional R-Win key on my keyboard that didn't come with one using AutoHotKey?

Comment: Do you mean to use AppsKey instead of RWin? RCtrl::AppsKey

Comment: No I mean R-Win. A keyboard shortcut in the software, for example, is R-Win + R-Alt + N. It's extremely particular and only works with R-Win, not L-Win.

Answer (score 0):

I think its the menumaskey. mine is Lctrl, which will fire at odd times, so idk.
Cant test this, so hope this does something for ya. staight remap for me stuck the rwin down.

```
#MenuMaskKey vk07
RCtrl::
send,{RWin Down}
return
RCtrl Up::
send,{RWin Up}
return
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Unfortunately this has a similar problem to the OP code where it works fine when pressing R-Ctrl by itself. But if I press R-Ctrl and R-Alt, I get a R-Ctrl and R-Alt keycode sent with no R-Win at all. This is according to PassMark KeyboardTest. The other software doesn't recognize the shortcut either.